# Delphi - How set SoapClient Timeout?

Tags: delphi, soap, timeout

I'm doing this before post:

FTimeout := 30000;

```
InternetSetOption(Pointer(@Data), INTERNET_OPTION_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, Pointer(@FTimeOut), SizeOf(FTimeOut));
InternetSetOption(Pointer(@Data), INTERNET_OPTION_SEND_TIMEOUT, Pointer(@FTimeOut), SizeOf(FTimeOut));
InternetSetOption(Pointer(@Data), INTERNET_OPTION_RECEIVE_TIMEOUT, Pointer(@FTimeOut), SizeOf(FTimeOut));
```

But don't works.

Someone can help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That should work. You don't say where you call it from, but I call mine in the OnBeforePost handler.

My function looks like this:

```
function SetTimeout(const HTTPReqResp: THTTPReqResp; Data: Pointer; NumSecs : integer) : boolean;
var
  TimeOut: Integer;
begin
  // Sets the receive timeout. i.e. how long to wait to 'receive' the response
  TimeOut := (NumSecs * 1000);
  try
    InternetSetOption(Data, INTERNET_OPTION_RECEIVE_TIMEOUT,  Pointer(@TimeOut),  SizeOf(TimeOut));
    InternetSetOption(Data, INTERNET_OPTION_SEND_TIMEOUT,  Pointer(@TimeOut),  SizeOf(TimeOut));
  except on E:Exception do
    raise Exception.Create(Format('Unhandled Exception:[%s] while setting timeout to [%d] - ',[E.ClassName, TimeOut, e.Message]));
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Maybe yours works and you don't have a long enough time to see?  An easy mistake would be to assume seconds, when it's MS.  I use SoapUI with a delay in the response, so I can "for sure" know that this works.

Comment: One might also check the return value of [`InternetSetOption`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385114(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Call GetLastError to see what error code may be set by internetSetOption.

Comment: ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE
6 (0x6)
The handle is invalid.

Comment: So I expect that you have your code in the wrong place.  Where are you calling it from?  It should be the OnBeforePost method of the RIO.  Also, try replacing Pointer(@Data) with just Data, as in my example.

Comment: I fix my InternetSetOption, now is returning True. But im setting timeout with 50000, and Excetion throws with 42 seconds. If i set timeout with 120000, exception throws with 42 again. Timeout have a maximum range?

Comment: I've set the timeout up to 15 minutes, and it's honoring the timeout.

Comment: Perform a sanity test in the other direction. If you set the timeout to 1000, does it timeout after 1 second? It should.  If not, then you are doing something wrong.

Comment: Look the test results:
5000 = Exception throws with 4,7 -
10000 = Exception throws with 9,1 -
20000 = Exception throws with 21,2 -
25000 = Exception throws with 42,2 -
30000 = Exception throws with 42,2 -
40000 = Exception throws with 42,2 -

if > 20 the exception throws with 42 :(

Comment: And what exception does it throw?  Read Timeout? Connect Timeout? Something else?